# `cygrunsrv`: How to control when my service reports successful start to the SCM?

Tags: windows-services, cygwin

I have about a dozen cygwin-based Windows services that depend on the state of an application started during Windows startup (not as a service, because it needs to interact with the user). These services should not start until the application reaches a specific desired state.

I have written a small program (let's call it `app-ready`) which periodically checks the state of the application. Now I wish for this program to run as a service upon which the abovementioned services will depend, so that Windows does not start the dependent services before this `app-ready` service indicates that the application has reached the desired state.

The general way to do this is to keep the `app-ready` service in `SERVICE_START_PENDING` state as long as we are waiting for the application to reach the desired state -- and when that happens, the `app-ready` service should transition from `SERVICE_START_PENDING` to `SERVICE_RUNNING`. This indicates to the [SCM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-control-manager) that the dependent services may now start.

However, `cygrunsrv` is executing the desired application in a separate thread and handles all SCM callbacks and status reporting on its own -- our application `app-ready` does not get a chance to hook into these and thus cannot control the service status explicitly.

**Is there a way to use `cygrunsrv` to manage a cygwin-based Windows service, so that we can control when the service is reported as `SERVICE_RUNNING`?**

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is a neat way to abuse the functionality of `cygrunsrv` to do what we want.

`cygrunsrv` supports this option:

```
-x, --pidfile <file>      Optional path for .pid file written by application
                          after fork().
                          Default is that application must not fork().
```

With a little help from the [`cygrunsrv` sources](https://cygwin.com/git/cygwin-apps/cygrunsrv.git) it can be seen that with this option, `cygrunsrv` switches into a special mode where it waits for the actually started program to terminate, and the `pidfile` to update its contents (or gets created). This new process is then monitored as the actual process behind the cygwin-based Windows service.

During the period of time where the initially started program (with the `--pidfile` option) still runs, `cygrunsrv` logs this via `syslog`:

```
...app-ready: PID 5000: service `app-ready': waiting for fork of 5001 (#1)
...app-ready: PID 5000: service `app-ready': waiting for fork of 5001 (#2)
...
```

and switches to the following, after the started program terminates:

```
...app-ready: PID 5000: service `app-ready': waiting for file /tmp/app-ready.pid (#6)
...app-ready: PID 5000: service `app-ready': waiting for file /tmp/app-ready.pid (#7)
...
```

until the pid file is written, and then it reports:

```
...app-ready: PID 5000: service `app-ready' started, pid 5002 read from /tmp/app-ready.pid
```

This behavior can be (mis)used to simply wait for arbitrary conditions to be met before daemonizing a child process (which must then run indefinitely), and this will achieve the behavior we want.

---

Sample script that can be used as the `app-ready` service:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
sleep 5 # wait for some condition to become fulfilled
(
    echo $BASHPID > /tmp/app-ready.pid # do this when finally ready (NB: $$ is the top-level PID)
    tail -f /dev/null # run forever -- or periodically check the condition and terminate
) & # background the long-running child process
# top-level exits normally immediately
```

Install like this:

```
cygrunsrv --install app-ready \
          --user $USER \
          --passwd $PASSWD \
          --path /bin/bash \
          --args '-c ~/bin/app-ready' \
          --type auto \
          --pidfile /tmp/app-ready.pid \
          --timeout 600 \
          --neverexits
```

Now, the service will show as "Starting" during the 5-second sleep, and will show as started after the PID is written to the pidfile. This allows us to do arbitrary work/waiting after starting the service, but before it shows up as started.

The `--timeout 600` option allows us to prolong the default maximum of 30 seconds that `cygrunsrv` will wait for the fork and the pidfile to be written.

Without the `--neverexits` option, if our service terminates, `cygrunsrv` will report an *intended* service stop to the SCM. With this option, an exit is considered a failure, `cygrunsrv` terminates without sending `SERVICE_STOPPED` to the SCM. The SCM, in turn, also considers this as a failure and triggers any recovery actions configured for the service
-- this may be useful, depending on the use-case. For example, a simple service restart may be meaningful, which will put the service in the "Starting" state again, until the conditions are fulfilled a second time.